# run function if EITHER statement is true

Tags: javascript, jquery

This below is a snippet from the code that I am working on. The short version of this is when a radio button with a label of **NO** is NOT checked, then the details textbox will show. I simply want to add another condition which allows the box to be shown IF another label is checked.

Example: IF 'NO' OR 'HOW MANY PEOPLE' are checked, then show the textbox.

I have been trying using the pipes but to no success.

```
if ($this.siblings('label').text() != 'No') {                            
   if ($this.is(':checked')) {                                 
      $details.show();                              
     $prompt.hide();                           
   }
}
```

Thanks to anyone in advance, I know this is a simple question Im just a bit stuck!

Comment: Checking for `.text()` is usually bad. It's much better to set a `data-something` attribute and then use `.data('something')`. Why? You might internationalize your program at some point and then you really don't want that code to ever use localized data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an OR boolean :

```
if ($this.siblings('label').text() != 'No' || $this.is(':checked'))
      $details.show();                              
      $prompt.hide();
}
```

In your case, you were doing an AND boolean (which is coded in javascript by **&&**)

More info on javascript booleans here : http://www.quirksmode.org/js/boolean.html

Max

Comment: Use `$this[0].checked` or `this.checked`.  `is()` is a powerful tool but it's slow in comparison to direct property access.

Comment: Also worth noting that if you want to go the jQuery route, jQuery 1.6+ allows `$this.prop("checked")`, which will return `true` or `false`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Max but I was looking for a solution that allows radio buttons with different labels to be checked and show the textbox in one statement. Therefore of one of the two instances are correct, show the textbox. The ` if ($this.is(':checked')) {` works when the radio button is checked as NO.

Comment: @jamessmyth: you should edit your post with this piece of information *and* with your HTML because a *radio* button cannot be "checked" (it has a value) but a checkbox *can* be checked